# question on semimartingales and jump processes

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am trying to understand a jump diffusion process of peter tankov. I studied economics, so i don't understand a lot about stochastic calculus. At a certain point, i have this equation:

$\frac{dC_t}{C_{t-}}=mdZ_t+\left(1-m\right)dR_t$

And after applying ito's lem:

$ \frac{dC_t^\star}{C_t^\star}=m(dZ_t-d[Z,R]_t-dR_t+d[R]_t)$

What the brackets mean? What kind of processes are this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer until you tell us more about the (original) equation. What are $Z_t$ and $R_t$?

Comment: Thanks for the answer
Theyre both discontinous processes, modelled as semimartingales $dZ_t=\frac{dS_t}{S_t-}$ and $dR_t=\frac {dB_t}{B_t-}$ where S and B are the value of two investment assets